# viewport > iframe > body > width 100% stops at 320px

Tags: iframe, width, viewport

I have an 90% width iframe as popup (5% left margin) and I have a viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1"

I have my body width on the src document at 100%. The issue is when I shrink the browser window its narrowest, the body stops shrinking at a 320px and extends outside the iframe. Although hidden, the content inside has % width issues, i.e. 100% is relative to the over-extending / hidden body.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I added a min-width:0 on the body element of the src document and that worked. I didn't realize there are built-in min-widths because I hadn't specified 320px anywhere, inline or in any css.